# Sharepoint putting extra "src" information in <img> tags

Tags: javascript, spservices

I'm trying to find a resolution to a problem i have never came across previously.

I have created a quill rich text editor where i intend to put text and images that i can store as html in SharePoint lists (using SP Services) in order to load it on a custom landing page instead of updating the html code itself every time there is new content.

While storing formatted text works perfectly, i am facing an issue whereas `<img>` tags get altered by SharePoint by adding an extra URL in them before the actual URL of the image. I'm using SP Services to upload images to a document library. This makes the `<img src=""` property incorrect and the image doesnt load. I tried with reading the element from the DOM and altering the property with `javacript.replace`, but whenever i load the corrected code back to the DOM, SharePoint puts the extra (wrong) link snippet back to its place.

example:

URL of the image i upload as html code into a list:

```
<div class="">
  <p>
    <img class="class" src="https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/PortalName/DocumentLibraryname/image.jpg" data-themekey="">
  </p>
</div>
```

Then what comes out when rendering the DOM is:

```
<div class="">
  <p>
    <img class="class" src="**https://company.sharepoint.com/pages/%22**https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/PortalName/DocumentLibraryname/image.jpg" data-themekey="">
  </p>
</div>
```

i changed the opening and closing characters on purpose so this thread can accept it

Notice the addition of an extra url part in bold. I tried replacing the parts i dont need in "src" with javascript, and even though console.log-ing displays the corrected value, when i put it back as innerHTML to its place, the wrong link gets added back. The process of reading the content of a SharePoint list item, putting it into a var and replacing stuff is connected to an onClick event, therefore document.ready shouldn't be an issue.

Has anyone face this issue before?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

*update 20.02.2020. I have managed to resolve the issue by implementing a workaround as i don't have access to back-end. I wait for the page to render the images with incorrect SRC, then i loop through the images with JS and update attributes.

var functionalityArticle = [];

function getFunctionalityArticleContent() {

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {
    LoadFunctionalityArticle('313681bb-f0bb-44aa-9c0d-ee387cd08991');
    console.log("list read");
});
```

};

function LoadFunctionalityArticle(listId5) {

```
var context5 = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web5 = context5.get_web();
var list5 = web5.get_lists().getById(listId5);


var query5 = new SP.CamlQuery();
query5.set_viewXml();

var allItems5 = list5.getItems(query5);

context5.load(allItems5, 'Include(Title, Content)'); 

context5.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function () {

    onQuerySuccessLAV5(allItems5, function () {
        console.log("Functionality article content imported");


    });
}),
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailedLAV));
```

};

function onQuerySuccessLAV5(allItems5, callback) {
    console.log("success5");
    var ListEnumerator5 = allItems5.getEnumerator();
    functionalityArticle = [];

```
while (ListEnumerator5.moveNext()) {
    var listItemInfo = '';
    var currentItem5 = ListEnumerator5.get_current();


    /*upload list items into an array*/

    functionalityArticle.push({

        'Title': currentItem5.get_item('Title'),
        'Input': currentItem5.get_item('Content')

    });

}

callback();

inputFunctionalityContent();
```

};

function onQueryFailedEmp(sender, args) {
    alert('Error: ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
};

function inputFunctionalityContent() {
    functionalityArticle.forEach(function (entry) {
        if (entry.Title == "TrainingFeature") {
            var currentvalue = entry.Input;
            currentvalue = currentvalue.replace(/[/g, '<').replace(/]/g, '>').replace(/ /g, ' ');
            console.log("currentvalue", currentvalue);
            document.getElementById("functionalityArticle").innerHTML = currentvalue;
            console.log("entry", entry);
        }
    })
    console.log("functionalityArticle run");

};

function fixIMG() {

```
var getArticleDiv = document.getElementById("functionalityArticle");
var getImages = getArticleDiv.getElementsByTagName("img");

for (var i = 0; i < getImages.length; i++) {
    getImages[i].setAttribute("class", "displayedIMG");
    getImages[i].removeAttribute("data-updatedsrc", "");
    getImages[i].removeAttribute("data-themekey", "");
    getImages[i].removeAttribute("data-themingid", "");
    var oldSRC = getImages[i].getAttribute("src");
    var newSRC = oldSRC.replace("https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/CompanyPortal/Pages/%22", "");
    newSRC = newSRC.replace("%22", "");
    getImages[i].setAttribute("src", newSRC);

}
```

};

Comment: Could you please also include the code that is rendering this?

Comment: I actually managed to bypass this issue, since i cannot change anything on server side. I wait for the site to render the images with incorrect src, then i loop through them and edit the attributes so they appear. i was hoping for a more sophisticated solution but since it's only an admin page i have no issue having an additional button to fix images. I will include the code that i used to display the content.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your error, it seems to be working ok (apart from that regex that i'm not sure why you need). On the last console output of currentvalue, do the urls look ok or have they already been changed there? If so you could include your fix there...

Comment: On that console.log the values appear correct in console only, but when examining the DOM the wrong url is stilll there. Must be a server side confg

Comment: .. the fix is in the fixIMG function on the bottom

Comment: Regarding that regex, if you mean the part where i replace  < with [ i had to do it because apparently the sharepoint list column (multiple lines of text) did not save the html at all, so i had to trick it into thinking it is not html. our company has weird policies and we often need to use workarounds.

Comment: I see, it could possibly help to set the list column to text only, if it is set to rich text.